# How can i plot years that really appear on DataFrame? ggplot2, it plots years that didn't exist in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

i would like to do a graph like this one:

[image]

I've been trying to do a bar plot, but it shows years that aren't in the data frame, like 1995, 1996, 1997, etc.

This is my code:

```
#install.packages("reshape")

setwd('C:/Users/CO/Desktop')
library(ggplot2)
library(XLConnect)
library(reshape)

df <- loadWorkbook('Rev_final_papers.xlsx', create = TRUE) 
df1 <- readWorksheet(df, header = TRUE, sheet = 'PLOT1')
dat2 <- melt(df1,id.vars='Row.Labels')
sub2<-subset(dat2, value >=1)
s <- ggplot(sub2, 
 aes(x=sub2$Row.Labels, y=sub2$value, fill=sub2$variable))
s+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack", na.rm=TRUE) + 
 theme_classic() + scale_fill_grey(start = 0.2, end = 0.8) + 
 scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1)) +  
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1994, 2017, 1))
```

This is the output plot I'm getting:

[image]

How can I take those "blank" years out?

Comment: Try `x=as.factor(sub2$Row.Labels)` inside your `ggplot` command. A quick example why I think it will help. Check the differences here: `df = data.frame(year = c(2000,2001,2005),
                x = 1:3);

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(year), x))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack");

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, x))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack");`

Comment: also, remove your `scale_x_continuous()` specification

Comment: ...also! ;) Do not specify aesthetics inside of `aes()` using `$`. This: `aes(x=sub2$Row.Labels, y=sub2$value, fill=sub2$variable)` should be this: `aes(x=Row.Labels, y=value, fill=variable)`. The `data` argument tells ggplot where to find the columns.

Comment: To be honest Mr. Robert I'd prefer your plot rather than the one you want. it's important to quickly be able to spot years with no info (or missing info) :D That might mean something...

Comment: @AntoniosK, thanks for your help... i've found the solution :D

Comment: @BenBolker , big thanks!!!

Comment: Glad to help, but the other 2 comments are also important!

Comment: @joran, big thanks, i'm beginner using R, still basic things that i don't know. big thanks!

Comment: If the comments have led you to the solution, feel free to post an answer to your own question (this is not just allowed, but encouraged, on StackOverflow)